# Form value not consoling on submit, no error found

Tags: angular, angular-forms

In my `ngForm` all are ok. But I am not able to get the console value on submit. any one help me to know the issue here?

my ts file :

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { NgForm } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  selectedUser = {
    name: "",
    username: "",
    password: ""
  };

  patternName = /^[a-zA-Z ]{3,}$/;
  patternUsername = /^[a-z]{3,}$/;
  patternPassword = /\s/;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    console.log("submitted", form.value);
  }
}
```

and the html is :

```
<form
  class="form-horizontal"
  #formSignin="ngForm"
  (ngSubmit)="formSignin.valid && onSubmit(formSignin)"
>
  <div class="page-header"><h2>User Sign-in</h2></div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">Name</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      class="col-sm-4"
      #name="ngModel"
      name="name"
      id="name"
      placeholder="Enter Name"
      [(ngModel)]="selectedUser.name"
      required
      [pattern]="patternName"
    />
    <div *ngIf="formSignin.submitted && !name.valid">
      <span *ngIf="name.errors.required">Name must to be filled</span>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="name.errors?.pattern">
      Username should be min 3 charactors and alphabets only
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="username">User Name</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      class="col-sm-4"
      #username="ngModel"
      name="username"
      id="username"
      placeholder="Enter Username"
      [(ngModel)]="selectedUser.username"
      required
    />
    <div *ngIf="formSignin.submitted && !username.valid">
      <span *ngIf="username.errors.required">Username Must filled</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="password">Password</label>

    <input
      type="password"
      class="col-sm-4"
      #password="ngModel"
      name="password"
      [pattern]="patternPassword"
      id="password"
      placeholder="Enter Password"
      [(ngModel)]="selectedUser.password"
      required
    />

    <div *ngIf="formSignin.submitted && !password.valid">
      <span *ngIf="password.errors.required">Password required</span>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!password.errors?.required && !password.errors?.pattern">
      Space not allowed
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group d-flex">
    <label class="col-sm-2"></label>
    <div><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Live demo : https://codesandbox.io/s/wnj9nj1l55

Comment: your code and validation conditions are correct only thing is password pattern is not working can you please  explain that why you need that pattern

Comment: @Soumya I am looking to prevent "empty" space in password

Answer (score 1):

You didn't put the ngSubmit right..

The right way to do is to only assigned a function and in the function check if the form is valid !

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
if (form.valid) {
  console.log("submitted", form.value);
} else {
  console.log("form not valid !");
}
```

}

https://codesandbox.io/s/0xvky6woz0

**EDIT**
Your RegEx for the password is invalid, so even if the name and the username is valid, the password is not.. I don't know what you are looking for but something like this will work: `/^[a-z]+/i`


**EDIT 2**
And in case you want a password with everything except space: `/^[a-zA-Z_\-]+$/` 
Also, you had an error in your html file:

```
 <div *ngIf="!password.errors?.required && password.errors?.pattern">
  Space not allowed
</div>
```

Comment: My question is, when the form is correct, I am not getting a word as "submitted" -

Comment: i edit my answer @3gwebtrain and also the codesandbox, now, it's working !

Answer (score 0):

this is the working example you can try this 
https://codesandbox.io/s/lyqx80n32z

here i used password pattern it will not allow you to enter space in the password field

> patternPassword = /^\S{0,50}$/;

and modified your error message condition

```
 <div *ngIf="!password.errors?.required && password.errors?.pattern">
  Space not allowed
</div>
```